# Upgrading DynamoDB to AWS-SDK v3 but can't update more than twice without error

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Updating my DynamoDB client to the latest AWS-SDK v3. As far as I'm aware, the actual expression for updating a DynamoDB table hasn't changed in the SDK crossover but using the new `UpdateCommand` isn't performing the same as the previous `update` command.

Client Initialisation:

```
const dynamoDB = (accessKey, secretAccess) => {
  if (!docClient) {
    docClient = DynamoDBDocument.from(
      new DynamoDBClient({
        region: 'local',
        maxAttempts: 3,
        endpoint: 'http://docker.for.mac.localhost:8000',
      }),
      {
        marshallOptions: {
          removeUndefinedValues: true,
        },
      },
    );
  }
  return docClient;
};
```

Using my client to send an update command:

```
    await dynamoDB().send(
      new UpdateCommand({
        TableName: process.env.TABLE_NAME,
        Key: { pk: bId },
        UpdateExpression: 'set blogEvents = list_append(if_not_exists(blogEvents, :emptyList), :newEvent)',
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
          ':newEvent': [blogEvent],
          ':emptyList': [],
        },
      }),
    );
```

I can successfully hit the above command twice before I eventually hit a 500 error that is giving me nothing to debug on. The error is: `The request processing has failed because of an unknown error, exception or failure.` My stack gives me nothing else.

I am using the `DynamoDBDocument` and `DynamoDBClient`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't show your client initialisation but your code seems wrong compared to how it's usually written.

`dynamoDB` which should be your client is not a function, yet you use a brackets after it `()`.

```
//Create client 
//Wrap client with document client 

await docClient.send(
      new UpdateCommand({
        TableName: process.env.TABLE_NAME,
        Key: { pk: bId },
        UpdateExpression: 'set blogEvents = list_append(if_not_exists(blogEvents, :emptyList), :newEvent)',
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
          ':newEvent': [blogEvent],
          ':emptyList': [],
        },
      }),
    );
```

Comment: Apologies, I didn't show my client initialisation because I didn't think it would be the issue here. I'll update my question to show the client configuration.

Comment: I would say that the added code changes the situation significantly, not least that you appear to be connecting to either a local proxy or DynamoDB Local.

Comment: Yeah, the issue I'm seeing is locally. I'm trying to make sure the app retains the same functionality upgrading from v2 to v3, which happens to include hitting a local dynamoDB. I can spin up a client (using the code I included) and Query the DB as well as Update the document, but I can only update the document twice. If I attempt to update my db a third time, the client blows up and throws the error mentioned above